# Unexpected Number : Syntax Error in csv-parser module on Node.js on loading CSV File

Tags: node.js, csv, express, parsing, rest

I am getting a Syntax Error Whilst Reading a CSV file with FS module and csv-parser.

When I do the same process without using it in a REST API, it works just fine, even console.logs to the screen.

The error came about when I was sending the data over the network in a REST API.

Find the Screenshots attached.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/) of `createReadStream`, it expects the path to the file rather than the `file` itself.

Hence, on line `7`, change it to :

```
const dataPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './data/metering_data.csv);
```

And then read the file using `createReadStream` as `fs.createReadStream(dataPath);`

Make sure you've imported the `path` module at the start of your file as following:

`var path = require('path')`

Comment: Thank you Sir! The Error was fixed my API is working accordingly.